# Как решать проблемы с точностью дробных? Хотя бы до шестого знака после запятой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пробую работать с временем и числами.
То есть иногда приходится считать время числами по секундам, и секунды преобразовывать в числа. Всё это дело перемножать, складывать, делить.

В итоге время и числа должны сходиться один в один.

Время, как я понял, считается в секундах до шестого знака после запятой, и deltatime проблем не возникает. Но когда считаю числами, то иногда не совпадает на два последних знака. То есть получается точно считать только до четвёртого знака после запятой.

Или я что-то не так делаю?

Вузов не заканчивал, поясните пожалуйста как правильно обходить неточности при расчётах дробных чисел в питоне.

Comment: Чтобы считать с ограниченной точностью, используйте тип [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

Comment: @insolor, у меня не получилось. Там тоже точность теряется, и нельзя одновременно считать десятки миллионов и просто десятки с одинаковой точностью. Тогда десятки миллионов будут округляться до целых.

Comment: На практике высокая точность не всегда нужна. Если вам нужно считать время, зачем вам нужна точность выше, допустим одной тысячной секунды?

Comment: @insolor, ну то понятно. Можно и время округлить, и числа. До сотых, до десятых. То есть единственная возможность решать проблему с точностью - это округлять ещё ближе к запятой?

Comment: Да, два варианта - или смириться с тем, что у вас в последних знаках (миллионных, например) могут вычисления не сходиться, или округлять до вменяемого количества знаков.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, я вот только не понимаю. Время же до шестого знака после запятой считается без потери точности?

Comment: Тип float без потери точности может хранить около 15 десятичных знаков (в обе стороны - перед запятой и после запятой). Обычно этого достаточно. В практически задачах на точность больше скольки-то знаков после запятой можно просто забить. Для времени вам зачем 6 знаков после запятой?

Comment: минимальный пример кода покажите, в котором у вас точность теряется. Если вы хотите только умножать, складывать, делить, то `fractions.Fraction` бесконечную точность даёт, но может быть не практично (из-за конечной памяти компьютера и медленности). Как вычисления с заданной [конечной] точностью производить, очевидно от вычислений зависит (к примеру, если вы вычислительно неустойчивый алгоритм используете, то никакой приближённый тип вас не спасёт). Вот [пример, где на 20 порядков разница для одного и того же алгоритма с точными вычислениями (Fraction) и приближёнными](https://goo.gl/LnKFF6)

Comment: @insolor, не знал что до 15, спасибо. У меня не больше, но точность теряется, на последних двух.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за подсказку на счёт модуля. Подумаю как воспроизвести ошибку и пример кода.

Comment: @jfs посмотрел как в deltatime решают проблему с точностью. Они просто умножают  на  `10**6`, потом делят на `10**6`. Это же нормальный способ?

Comment: "нормальность" зависит от задачи. В общем случае это конечно не работает. Об арифметике с datetime можете думать как о целочисленной арифметики в микросекундах (эпоха `datetime.min`). Если вы хотите деление поддерживать, то вы точный результат используя только целые числа в общем случае не получите (к примеру, так как `1//3==0` и `2//3 == 0`—имея `0` и `3` вы не сможете узнать что на входе у вас было `1` или `2`). Потеря одной цифры может в зависимости от алгоритма быстро привести к потере всех значимых цифр (я же вам явно привёл пример: за 23 шага результат от точного в 100000000000000000000.

Comment: раз отличается (то есть мусор в ответе получился при использовании конечной точности и алгоритма из примера). В зависимости от задачи могут быть алгоритмы, которые приближённый, но точный результат (imprecise but accurate), позволяют получить, используя приближённые вычисления (fixed/floating point).